# kdeinit5: Segmentation fault

Tags: linux, opensuse, kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace

I am experiencing a problem with KDE in my OpenSuse 42.1 Leap OS.
Basically, everything that requires Qt does not work (kate, Libreoffice, dolphin etc).

When I click on an icon's application I get an error message. Usually something like: "KDEInit could not launch '/usr/bin/kate"ls
But sometimes also: " Error - Plasma: Internal Error. Please send a full bug report to http://bugs.kde.org. Unknown error condition in stat: No route to host"

At startup I usually I get the following message: "We are sorry Init5 closed unexpectedly. You cannot report this error, because kdeinit5 does not provide a bug reporting address. " 
"Details: Executable: kdeinit5 PID: 1866 Signal: Segmentation fault(11) Time.. "
The full crash message is the one quoted at the end of the thread.

I have another PC where it is installed the same operating system and configured in the same way. Both systems used to work well. Perhaps the one that is now reporting this messages has has been modified by someone else.
In both of them I installed Qt5.5.0 in /opt. I remember that there were problems if the /opt/Qt5.5.0/..lib path is set in /etc/ld.so.conf, but in the file there's no mention of qt.

Some other info (both systems):

```
Kernel version: linux-e5re 4.1.12-1-default

linux-e5re:~ # qmake --version
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /usr/lib64
```

I had some problems similar to this and I fixed them with:

```
go in /opt/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/bin
mv qdbus qdbus-qt5
```

I have checked in /usr/bin and there is both qdbus and qdbus-qt5

So far nothing I have read in other forums has been useful.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

```
Application: kdeinit5 (kdeinit5), signal: Segmentation fault
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7fb25b8fb740 (LWP 1690))]


Thread 6 (Thread 0x7fb2474ef700 (LWP 1693)):
#0 0x00007fb259c93c1d in poll () at /lib64/libc.so.6
#1 0x00007fb259199422 in () at /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1
#2 0x00007fb25919b00f in xcb_wait_for_event () at /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1
#3 0x00007fb249e75c29 in () at /usr/lib64/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#4 0x00007fb25a00855f in () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#5 0x00007fb2576ae0a4 in start_thread () at /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#6 0x00007fb259c9c04d in clone () at /lib64/libc.so.6


Thread 5 (Thread 0x7fb23af0b700 (LWP 1702)):
#0 0x00007fb259c93c1d in poll () at /lib64/libc.so.6
#1 0x00007fb2569f2e64 in () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2 0x00007fb2569f319a in g_main_loop_run () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3 0x00007fb23b823426 in () at /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0
#4 0x00007fb256a17f65 in () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5 0x00007fb2576ae0a4 in start_thread () at /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#6 0x00007fb259c9c04d in clone () at /lib64/libc.so.6


Thread 4 (Thread 0x7fb2394ad700 (LWP 1723)):
#0 0x00007fb259c93c1d in poll () at /lib64/libc.so.6
#1 0x00007fb2569f2e64 in () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2 0x00007fb2569f2f7c in g_main_context_iteration () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3 0x00007fb25a239a5b in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#4 0x00007fb25a1e0a63 in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#5 0x00007fb25a00384a in QThread::exec() () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#6 0x00007fb23ddc0b77 in KCupsConnection::run() () at /usr/lib64/libkcupslib.so
#7 0x00007fb25a00855f in () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#8 0x00007fb2576ae0a4 in start_thread () at /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#9 0x00007fb259c9c04d in clone () at /lib64/libc.so.6


Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fb238cac700 (LWP 1724)):
#0 0x00007fb256a34cf9 in g_mutex_lock () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#1 0x00007fb2569f2e4a in () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2 0x00007fb2569f2f7c in g_main_context_iteration () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3 0x00007fb25a239a5b in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#4 0x00007fb25a1e0a63 in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#5 0x00007fb25a00384a in QThread::exec() () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#6 0x00007fb25a00855f in () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#7 0x00007fb2576ae0a4 in start_thread () at /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#8 0x00007fb259c9c04d in clone () at /lib64/libc.so.6


Thread 2 (Thread 0x7fb22af13700 (LWP 2183)):
#0 0x00007fb25a2397c8 in () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#1 0x00007fb2569f24ad in g_main_context_prepare () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2 0x00007fb2569f2d80 in () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3 0x00007fb2569f2f7c in g_main_context_iteration () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4 0x00007fb25a239a5b in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#5 0x00007fb25a1e0a63 in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#6 0x00007fb25a00384a in QThread::exec() () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#7 0x00007fb25a00855f in () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#8 0x00007fb2576ae0a4 in start_thread () at /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#9 0x00007fb259c9c04d in clone () at /lib64/libc.so.6


Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fb25b8fb740 (LWP 1690)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6 0x00007fb249c34720 in XGetXCBConnection () at /usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1
#7 0x00007fb229e79dc6 in () at /usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/kded_touchpad.so
#8 0x00007fb229e5c744 in TouchpadBackend::implementation() () at /usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/kded_touchpad.so
#9 0x00007fb229e71f74 in () at /usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/kded_touchpad.so
#10 0x00007fb229e5c5e8 in () at /usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/kded_touchpad.so
#11 0x00007fb259971be0 in KPluginFactory::create(char const*, QWidget*, QObject*, QList<QVariant> const&, QString const&) () at /usr/lib64/libKF5CoreAddons.so.5
#12 0x00007fb24a32a5e4 in () at /usr/lib64/libkdeinit5_kded5.so
#13 0x00007fb24a32b6bf in () at /usr/lib64/libkdeinit5_kded5.so
#14 0x00007fb24a32e445 in () at /usr/lib64/libkdeinit5_kded5.so
#15 0x00007fb24a32ea33 in () at /usr/lib64/libkdeinit5_kded5.so
#16 0x00007fb252469d34 in () at /usr/lib64/libQt5DBus.so.5
#17 0x00007fb25246e302 in () at /usr/lib64/libQt5DBus.so.5
#18 0x00007fb25246ee13 in () at /usr/lib64/libQt5DBus.so.5
#19 0x00007fb2524708be in () at /usr/lib64/libQt5DBus.so.5
#20 0x00007fb25a213796 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#21 0x00007fb25886ce8c in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#22 0x00007fb258871cd8 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#23 0x00007fb25a1e2ba5 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#24 0x00007fb25a1e4d67 in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#25 0x00007fb25a23a5c3 in () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#26 0x00007fb2569f2c84 in g_main_context_dispatch () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#27 0x00007fb2569f2ed8 in () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#28 0x00007fb2569f2f7c in g_main_context_iteration () at /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#29 0x00007fb25a239a3c in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#30 0x00007fb25a1e0a63 in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#31 0x00007fb25a1e85d6 in QCoreApplication::exec() () at /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
#32 0x00007fb24a32c1b6 in kdemain () at /usr/lib64/libkdeinit5_kded5.so
#33 0x0000000000408cb3 in ()
#34 0x0000000000405cee in main ()
```

Comment: What's your `$XDG_CONFIG_DIR` set to?

Comment: Hello, I checked, it is /etc/xdg

Comment: My mistake, I meant to ask what your `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` is

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Qt?